# SSH into windows 10 pc with Termux using keypair

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh, ssh-keys, termux

So i want to SSH into my windows 10 pc via termux

On server windoes 10 pc:
1.)installed OpenSSH using optional windows features.
2.)enabled the respective services

On client termux app:
-generated keypair using `ssh-keygen -t ed25519`

Again on the server windows 10 pc
-ran the following command:`powershell New-Item -Force -ItemType Directory -Path $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh; Add-Content -Force -Path $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\authorized_keys -Value '<MY KEY>'`

The problem is even after all this, it keeps asking for password..any help appreciated.

Log file location at `C:\ProgramData\ssh\logs` is empty

config file at `C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config`:

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
StrictModes no
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```